# Array of object reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

In my reactjs application I am passing array of object to my component. And inside that component I am using the object to map and create multiple object but the problem is somehow I am getting errors

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

this is my code where I declare my object in state in my parent

```
  this.state = EditMultiObject: [
        {
          id: 0,
          Title: ""
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          Title: ""
        }
      ]
    };

<Form1
              EditMultiObject={this.EditMultiObject} />
```

In my Form1 component here is my code

```
 const {
        EditMultiObject

      } = props;
      return (

    {EditMultiObject.map((counter, key) => (
              <SubFormEditCom
                key={key}
              />
            ))}

)
```

Did I made anything wrong with this?

Comment: This is the simplify the code but hopefully you still get what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to change it to this:

```
this.state = {
   myobjects: [{ id: 0, Title: ' '},{id: 1, Title: ' '}],
};

 <Form1 EditMultiObject={this.state.myobjects} />
```

And should be ok

Comment: Omg I overlook that "this". Man I should hit the sack this is a sign that I am tired

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the code

```
this.state = {
     EditMultiObject: [
        {
          id: 0,
          Title: "title1"
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          Title: "title2"
        }
      ]
    };

 <Form1 EditMultiObject={this.state.EditMultiObject} />
```

Then in your Form1 component

```
render(){
  const {EditMultiObject}=this.props;

    return (

    { EditMultiObject && EditMultiObject.length > 0 ?  // check length of an array then use map
              EditMultiObject.map((counter, key) => (
              <SubFormEditCom
                key={key}
              /> : null}
            ))}

)
```